# Having multiple mod rewrite rules to satisfy different urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm working with mod rewrites and i am new at it. I have written the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? index.php?company=$1&action=$2&type=$3&id=$4           [L,QSA]
```

i have tested and it works however it is not allowing me to display images e.g.

```
<img src="http://example.com/images/logo.gif">
```

because it keeps following the rewrite rule and suggests that this page doesn't exist

How do i go about adding exclusions to a certain directory so that i can use it as an image/js/css directory etc.

Thank you very much

Comment: Add exclusion rules PRIOR to the other rule posted. End them with [L]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're best off simply excluding requests that match a file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not if the request matches a real file
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/...
```